# SQL Server 2012 - sp_executesql multiple parameter error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am receiving an error when attempting to execute the following code that builds a dynamic string to be executed by sp_executesql.

```
DECLARE @paramDefinition NVARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @ID1 NVARCHAR(20);
DECLARE @StageTable1 NVARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @StageTable2 NVARCHAR(100);

SET @ID1 = '111111111111111111';
SET @StageTable1 = 'TestTable1';
SET @StageTable2 = 'TestTable2';

DECLARE @sqlToExecute NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @tableCreateSQL = 'SELECT @ID1
                       INTO   @StageTable1 
                       FROM   @StageTable2 ';

SET @paramDefinition = '@ID1 NVARCHAR(20), 
                        @StageTable1 NVARCHAR(100), 
                        @StageTable2 NVARCHAR(100)';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @tableCreateSQL, 
                       @paramDefinition, 
                       @ID1,
                       @StageTable1, 
                       @StageTable2;
```

The error I receive states the following:

```
Incorrect syntax near '@StageTable1'.
```

Am I incorrectly constructing the SQL string, or is there an issue with the sp_executesql statement?

Comment: You can't use variable as a table name. You'll have to concatenate it to the SQL text, but beware of SQL injections

Comment: You are missing quiet a lot .. refer to [sp_executesql - examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't parameterize column and table names, sorry. You'll need to do this the old way:

```
SET @tableCreateSQL = N'SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(@ID1) + N'
               INTO   dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@StageTable1) + N'
               FROM   dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@StageTable2) + N';';
```

Also see:

- [Protecting Yourself from SQL Injection in SQL Server - Part 1](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3637/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server---part-1/)
- [Protecting Yourself from SQL Injection in SQL Server - Part 2](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3638/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server---part-2/)